# js - Issue get text using previouselementsibling

Tags: javascript, get, element

I try to get text **GET THIS TEXT** using this code, but still fail. 
Can you analyze whats the wrong?

```
<table class="table  table-bordered" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"><div id="foto"><img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000163861066/61dee118c22e6ddb6fea2ffdb2957bd7_normal.jpeg"></div></td>
<td><div id="tweet31898">**GET THIS TEXT**</div>    
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="pos31898" value="POS" onclick="addPOS(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+' ');"><span class="label label-success">Pos</span>
<input type="radio" name="pos31898" value="NON" onclick="addNON(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+' ');"><span class="label label-warning">Non</span>
<input type="radio" name="pos31898" value="NEG" onclick="addNEG(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+' ');"><span class="label label-important">Neg</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for instance at `pos31898`, it *has* no `previousElementSibling`, it's the first element in its container. This is more obvious if you indent the HTML:

```
<table class="table  table-bordered" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <div id="foto"><img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000163861066/61dee118c22e6ddb6fea2ffdb2957bd7_normal.jpeg"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="tweet31898">**GET THIS TEXT**</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="pos31898" value="POS" onclick="addPOS(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+' ');"><span class="label label-success">Pos</span>
        <input type="radio" name="pos31898" value="NON" onclick="addNON(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+' ');"><span class="label label-warning">Non</span>
        <input type="radio" name="pos31898" value="NEG" onclick="addNEG(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML+' ');"><span class="label label-important">Neg</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The easy way, of course, is `document.getElementById("tweet31898")`, since there's an `id` on the `div`. Since your radio buttons have that number in their `name`, you can derive the `id` using `this.name.replace('pos', 'tweet')`. E.g.:

```
onclick="addPOS(document.getElementById(this.name.replace('pos', 'tweet')).innerHTML + ' ')"
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/acacez/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/acacez/1/edit)

But doing it structurally, you want `parentNode` to get to the `td`, then again to get to the `tr`, then `previousElementSibling` to get the previous `tr`, then `lastElementChild` to go down to the `td`, then `firstElementChild` to get to the `div`:

```
onclick="addPOS(this.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.innerHTML + ' ')"
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/acacez/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/acacez/2/edit)

Comment: thanks for the response crowder. i know if using get elemetn by id, but i have case like my post above, sadly i cant using getelementbyid

Comment: @user2597016: You can with what you've posted, note the example. But as you were commenting I was writing up how to do it structurally.

Comment: Hi @Crowder, is it visible to me to use combination of previous-afterelement sibling?

Comment: @user2597016: It's at the end of the answer, first as text explaining it, then as code. (I just noticed an error in it and fixed it.)